# VB.net Random Pin Generator Program Overflows

Tags: vb.net, random

I'm working on a random PIN generator program and am getting a mystery error here upon running it.

```
Shared Function CreatePIN() As Integer
    Dim PIN As String = ""
    ' Create the Random ID:
    Dim possible As String = "0123456789"
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        PIN += possible.Chars(Math.Floor(Rnd() * possible.Length) Mod possible.Length)
    Next
    Return Convert.ToInt32(PIN)
End Function
```

The error that I am getting is an overflow!  The int I am creating is either too large or too small to be an int.  How can this happen?  No way this program is creating an int that big... although apparently it is.

Comment: did you try Convert.ToInt64(PIN) ?

Comment: Still gives an overflow when using 64 bit int

Comment: A 64 bit int is large enough to hold the max number this function can generate (9,999,999,999), but you also need to update the return type of the function to return an `Int64` in that case.

Comment: even simpler fix would be to return a string.  Pins are rarely actual numeric types, and in this case once in a while the leading digit will get lost if it happens to be "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int maximum value is `2,147,483,647`

your code can generate `9,999,999,999`

use a long or change your code to make sure you wont generate a number over `2,147,483,647`

ex;

```
Function CreatePIN() As Long
    Dim PIN As String = ""
    ' Create the Random ID:
    Dim possible As String = "0123456789"
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        PIN += possible.Chars(CInt(Math.Floor(Rnd() * possible.Length) Mod possible.Length))
    Next
    Return Convert.ToInt64(PIN)
End Function
```

and a foot note; always turn on `option explicit ON` and `option strict ON`

Comment: Thank you for insight on this problem.  In fact, after thinking about the viability of a simple 32-bit integer as a PIN, I ended up fixing this problem by converting my PIN that i am creating to a string!!! Now I can have a huge, Alphanumeric PIN that is, along with a server request limit per day, virtually impossible to brute force guess.